# How plot multiple dictionaries of dataframes by columns ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib

I would like to plot multiple dictionaries of dataframes in the same figure with subplot. I can draw a dictionary of several dataframes on the same figure but I can't add another one.

```
keys = dfs.keys()

cols = 1
rows = 30

nb_figs = cols*rows

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(5, 150))

ax_array = ax.ravel()

# iterate through the dataframe dictionary keys and use enumerate
keys = sorted(dfs)
for idx, key in enumerate(keys[::150]):

    if idx >= nb_figs :
        break
    else:

        ax = dfs[key].plot(x='Timestamp', y='Value', ax= ax_array[idx])
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

- I would like to add a second column which would correspond to my second dataframes dictionary but do I have to make a for loop for the rows and columns to have a figure of dimension (36,2) ??
- How can I set the `ax = ax_array` or `ax`to be in the right column and row?

The figure must be :

````
|-----------|   |-----------|
|           |   |           |
|    dict1  |   |    dict2  |
|    df1    |   |    df1    |
|-----------|   |-----------|

|-----------|         .
|           |         .
|    dict1  |         .
|    df2    |
|-----------|



|-----------|   |-----------|
|           |   |           |
|    dict1  |   |    dict2  |
|    df30   |   |    df30   |
|-----------|   |-----------|

```
````

Comment: try looking up facet_grid in the seaborn library

Answer (score 1):

When you create `subplots` with `ncols>1` and `nrows>1`, you would get a two dimensional array of axis. So something like this:

```
cols = 2
rows = 30

nb_figs = cols*rows

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(5, 150))

for col, dfs in enumerate([dict1, dict2]):
    # use `.items()` to get pair of `key, value` so you don't need `dfs[key]`
    # or just `.values()` if you only need `data`
    for ax, (key, data) in zip(axes[:, col], dfs.items()):

        # plot data to ax
        data.plot(x='Timestamp', y='Value', ax=ax)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: yes but for each column I would like to set different axes and titles, with also colors. I don't know if it's possible with your method ?

Comment: Yes, why not? Do all `ax.set_tittle` inside the loop.

Comment: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_tittle'

Comment: @ThonyNadhir it's [`set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html), sorry for the typo.

Comment: My fault too, a stupid copy and paste. I also noticed that you removed my condition of displaying every 150 dataframes, however I absolutely need it, all the interest is there

Comment: I don't get it, you only have 30 rows/axes each column, why do you care about 150 dataframes?

Comment: no I have 150*30 = 4500 and I want to see all 150 to see the evolution

Comment: I also need a different color and a different name for each column.